# Django cannot find pattern name when redirecting

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

I am workign on django project, i have modified the default django user model to employee's model using AbstractUser model.

Now On their first login, i need to redirect employee's to change password page the Url for which is defined in the `EmployeeAdmin - get_urls` method. Also to override the default login behaviour i had to override the default AdminSite as shown below:

**admin.py**

```
class MyAdminSite(AdminSite):
    login_form = AdminLoginForm


admin_site = HRMSAdminSite(name='My-admin')


@admin.register(Employee, site=admin_site)
class EmployeeAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_urls(self):
        return [
            path(
                '<id>/password/',
                self.admin_site.admin_view(self.user_change_password),
                name='auth_user_password_change',
            ),
        ] + super().get_urls()

    def user_change_password(self, request, id, form_url=''):
        pass
```

And on my AdminLoginForm i check for the first login of user:

**forms.py**

```
class AdminLoginForm(AuthenticationForm):

    def confirm_login_allowed(self, user):
        # user.last_login is blank if this is first login for this user
        if not user.last_login:
            return redirect('auth_user_password_change')
```

However, when running the above code i get below error:

**Reverse for 'auth_user_password_change' not found. 'auth_user_password_change' is not a valid view function or pattern name.**

I dont know why django cannot find the named url i.e defined inside EmployeeAdmin's get_urls() method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are adding the URL to a model admin class, you need to include the `admin` namespace to reverse it.

```
return redirect('admin:auth_user_password_change')
```